# TabBar Item To Show RootController - Container-Embedded NavigationController TableViewController Stacks

Tags: ios, swift, tabs, navigation

I have the following storyboard:

[image]

If the user navigates to view A1-2, then selects Tab B, then selects Tab A ... they will be presented with TableViewController A1-2 (their recent "Tab A exit point").

I would like them to be presented with TableViewController A1 if they navigate to Tab B then decide to 'go back' and select Tab A; NOT where they navigated to previously (i.e. TableViewController A1-2, or their recent "Tab A exit point").

Basically, any tab selected (other than the one currently selected) will present the root view controller of that particular tab.

Is this possible with my storyboard setup?

Many, many thanks for any feedback.

**ADDENDUM:**

Could I also go with the following code in view A1-2 (or A1-1, B1-2, B1-1):

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Thus effectively removing all views above the root view controller should the user switch tabs? And achieving my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have A1-2 and A1-1 dismissed upon tab-bar switch, and vise-versa if needed.

```
//set tab bar delegate and call this method
func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    if item == tabBarB {
        //dismiss viewController A1-2 and A1-1
        self.view.window!.viewControllerA1?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        //dismiss miss viewController B1-2 and B1-1
        self.view.window!.viewControllerB1?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: If you dismiss the root (A1), all the VC's on top of it should pop off the stack as well, thus always returning to A1.

Comment: Super stuff. Great logic. Thats exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: My earliest comment was made from my colleague's account. Hence the deletion. Thanks again. Solution is perfect for me.

Comment: Great to hear! Happy coding :)

Comment: Hi @Julian Lee. I'm having a bit of trouble adopting your code. I think the fact that I have child view controllers in my containers makes matters a bit more complex. I have added an ADDENDUM to my question with a possible alternative. Will that work also? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it out? It seems fine, as long as you know the only time you're going to remove a view is with the tab bar (ensure this doesn't get triggered by standard segues, closing modals, etc).

Comment: Yes, it seems to do the trick. I have also added     `navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)` to `viewDidDisappear` and `func willEnterBackground()` to cover all bases including he user leaving the app.

Comment: Depending on the scale of the app, I would consider making a separate method for viewDidDisappear and add `super.viewDidDisappear` to it (ditto for willEnterBackground), because these methods are so universal - unless you're sure that under every circumstance you want to pop to root.
But other than that, good job, you've made it even more efficient! I just figured you only wanted to pop on tab bar switch before, haha.

Comment: Lol. Yes (regards the tab bar switch reference) ...  I was also thinking I may have to amend `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` to cover the user back-swiping while in view A1-2. With my `popToRoot' strategy, this would send the user back 2 views to the rootViewController and not back one view/frame which is the norm.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was fearful of haha. But yeah, it's clear you've got this in the bag. Good work :)